Gram matrices and singular values dimension limits
Background
My book states that if

$A\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ and
$A=U\Sigma V^*$ is an SVD of $A$
$m\le n$

Then the Gram matrix $A^*A$ has an eigendecomposition where

The eigenvalues are powers of the singular values and
The eigenvectors are the right singular vectors

Problem
However, it seems to me like the 3rd requirement is not relevant and this is true for $m \gt n$ as well.
Question
Why is $m\le n$ required?

What book is this from?  Conclusion 1 seems to be false: consider a $1\times 2$ matrix  $A\neq \mathbf 0$-- it has a single singular value $\sigma_1 \neq 0$ but $A^*A$ is $2\times 2$ with rank one so it has an eigenvalue zero that is not a power of a singular value (some will try to abuse this with $-\infty$ as a power I suppose but that is non-standard at best and likely to cause other problems).

A matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ has $\max{m,n}$ singular values. It seems as if they are using the full SVD as opposed to the "thin" or reduced SVD. Conclusion 1 seems fine. As for why $m\leq n$ is required, consider $A\in 2\times 1$. $A$ has two singular values but $A^*A$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix.
